# return from browser to app in kiosk mode

Tags: android, android-intent, kiosk-mode

I'm working on an android app in kiosk mode.
Now I would like to open a browser window from my app, do stuff in there, and then return to my original app using the back button. I tried to do this using the following Intent:

```
Intent browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.de"));
startActivityForResult(browserIntent, 0);
```

This opens the browser as planned, but when I press the back arrow button, it says
`Screen is pinned. Unpinning isn't allowed by your organization.` 
When i close the browser using the browser's X button, it closes and I return to the app.
I use the same concept to open the wifi settings, and there it allows me to return to the app without complaining:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS), 0);
```

**How can I achieve the same behaviour for my browser intent?**
I assume there are flags that would do this, but I can't seem to find the right one.

---

**EDIT:**
Interestingly, this problem seems to occur only when the device has no wifi connection. I just tried the same with wifi enabled and the browser closes as intended when I touch the back button.

Comment: Have you considered using [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)? It might integrate better with kiosk mode than launching the browser.

Comment: @Fred Thanks, I'll take a look at that!

Comment: However, I would still be interested in a solution to my original question...